# Why do I get "Insufficient Privileges" in a DevOps pipeline creating an AD group with New-MgGroup with a service principal

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-graph-api, azure-powershell

I'm trying to replicate the following article as an Azure DevOps pipeline.

[E2E DevOps for Azure SQL with Managed Identities](https://medium.com/medialesson/e2e-devops-for-azure-sql-with-managed-identities-f2231c7e964c#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ijk4NmVlOWEzYjc1MjBiNDk0ZGY1NGZlMzJlM2U1YzRjYTY4NWM4OWQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.BGnY4OJ5-F8mfdPD9VreAwGhmamvWrSfvfeg59pkp-D0cMtLBMcI6jpNX6ztdaUi12SL3XfhJ4DtsN0bruZ53M_i56OvQ7yQNOmP9rHt20nwJyXDjFBLHci7LOI4u9isRUBlmw74ayG6fZh2UOQ0pkcnrsmGUvhUnDByF8tULCSGcgjkt1zy7fWFw6MeJL3S8G8LByoe2tjXLE-D1yz8wo6OXs_dOGguHfPyb-R3MCTpQK5rVeTi5l5NM-7-8iFwb-12lQucuk8JN9GufbqDfQSR3aoOOLwvTAc4WzrvSUn5WCFTpXDIGUbz0OzssdaiVyRp_kjLU4nTrBgnyGVVhQ)

There are several things I'm doing differently including:

- Using Azure DevOps service connection to create the service principal in Azure
- Manually going into Azure and adding Directory.ReadWrite.all and Group.ReadWrite.all to the service principal
- Create a new secret for the service principal (and string it in the DevOps project library to be passed to my PowerShell script).
- Using the above mentioned service principal in the pipeline PowerShell step (in place of the one from the article)
- Getting an auth02 token for the service principal and use it to login to MS Graph

The permissions are application, not delegated MS Graph permissions (for the service principal).  I know at least the Directory.ReadWrite.all is working, but it is required, for `az ad group create` and that works correctly.

The permissions have had consent granted.

As you can see in the source code below, I'm calling MS Graph with `Get-MgContext` to see what permissions I require, and also `(Find-MgGraphCommand -Command New-MgGroup).permissions` to verify that I have the correct permissions.

```
param([string]$tenantId, [string]$subscriptionId, [string]$resourceGroupName, [string]$location, [string]$azureServicePrincipalAppId, [string]$azureServicePrincipalPwd
# Yes - I know passwords should be [secure]

if(!$tenantId) {
    Write-Output "no value for tenantId"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "tenantId = $tenantId"
}
if(!$subscriptionId) {
    Write-Output "no value for subscriptionId"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "subscriptionId = $subscriptionId"
}
if(!$resourceGroupName) {
    Write-Output "no value for resourceGroupName"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "resourceGroupName = $resourceGroupName"
}
if(!$location) {
    Write-Output "no value for location"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "location = $location"
}
if(!$azureServicePrincipalAppId) {
    Write-Output "no value for azureServicePrincipalAppId"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "azureServicePrincipalAppId = $azureServicePrincipalAppId"
}
if(!$azureServicePrincipalPwd) {
    Write-Output "no value for azureServicePrincipalPwd"
    exit 1;
} else {
    Write-Output "azureServicePrincipalPwd = $azureServicePrincipalPwd"
}

$exitCode = 0

# Login to Azure and DevOps
Write-Output 'Auth exec: az login'
az login --service-principal -u "$azureServicePrincipalAppId" -p "$azureServicePrincipalPwd" --tenant "$tenantId" --allow-no-subscriptions

az --version

Write-Output 'Init exec: az account set --subscription'
az account set --subscription $subscriptionId

# See tutorial https://medium.com/medialesson/e2e-devops-for-azure-sql-with-managed-identities-f2231c7e964c

Write-Output 'exec: az group create'
az group create --name $resourceGroupName --location $location

# Security Group for database admins to be added to (including our service principal that runs the pipelin)
Write-Output 'exec: az ad group create --display-name TestDbAdmins'
$dbAdminGroupId = $(az ad group list --display-name TestDbAdmins | ConvertFrom-Json).Id

if ($dbAdminGroupId) {
    Write-Output "exec: TestDbAdmins already exists; id= $dbAdminGroupId"
} else {
    # Requires Microsoft Graph "Directory.ReadWrite.All" permission
    $dbAdminGroupId=$(az ad group create --display-name TestDbAdmins --mail-nickname TestDbAdmins | ConvertFrom-Json).Id
    Write-Output "exec output: dbAdminGroupId=$dbAdminGroupId"
}

if ($dbAdminGroupId) {
    # Azure managed identity for DevOps thatwill run the DevOps pipeline


        # The service principal for the pipeline requests the token
        Write-Output "6 Get accessToken"
        $url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"
        $scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        $credentialBody = @{
            tenant          = $tenantId
            grant_type      = 'client_credentials'
            client_id       = $azureServicePrincipalAppId
            client_secret   = $azureServicePrincipalPwd
            scope           = $scope
        }
            
        # Get the return Auth Token for the service principal identity
        $token = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Body $credentialBody

        # Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All", "Group.ReadWrite.All"
        Write-Output "exec: Connect to MS Graph"
        Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $token.access_token

        Write-Output "exec: Get service principal's permissions"
        Get-MgContext

        Write-Output "exec: What permissions are required for New-MgGroup?"
        (Find-MgGraphCommand -Command New-MgGroup).permissions


        Write-Output "exec: Create the New-MgGroup"
        $Group = New-MgGroup -DisplayName "TestDirectoryReaders" -MailNickName "TestDirectoryReaders" -MailEnabled:$False -SecurityEnabled:$True -IsAssignableToRole:$True -Description "A group for Database users"
}
```

For the sake of brevity, I've only added the output for the MS Graph calls (the rest all work and return values if interrogated).

```
exec: Connect to MS Graph
Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
exec: Get service principal's permissions

ClientId              : ***
TenantId              : xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
CertificateThumbprint : 
Scopes                : {Directory.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All}
AuthType              : UserProvidedAccessToken
AuthProviderType      : UserProvidedToken
CertificateName       : 
Account               : 
AppName               : tenant-TestOpStat-xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
                        b2
ContextScope          : Process
Certificate           : 
PSHostVersion         : 7.2.10

exec: What permissions are required for New-MgGroup?
Name            : Directory.ReadWrite.All
IsAdmin         : True
Description     : Read and write directory data
FullDescription : Allows the app to read and write data in your organization's 
                  directory, such as other users, groups.  It does not allow th
                  e app to delete users or groups, or reset user passwords.

Name            : Group.ReadWrite.All
IsAdmin         : True
Description     : Read and write all groups
FullDescription : Allows the app to create groups and read all group properties
                   and memberships on your behalf.  Additionally allows the app
                   to manage your groups and to update group content for groups
                   you are a member of.

Name            : Directory.ReadWrite.All
IsAdmin         : True
Description     : Read and write directory data
FullDescription : Allows the app to read and write data in your organization's 
                  directory, such as other users, groups.  It does not allow th
                  e app to delete users or groups, or reset user passwords.

Name            : Group.ReadWrite.All
IsAdmin         : True
Description     : Read and write all groups
FullDescription : Allows the app to create groups and read all group properties
                   and memberships on your behalf.  Additionally allows the app
                   to manage your groups and to update group content for groups
                   you are a member of.

exec: Create the New-MgGroup
New-MgGroup_CreateExpanded: /home/vsts/work/1/s/azure-pipelines/powershell-scripts/init-managed-identities.ps1:177
Line |
 177 |              $Group = New-MgGroup -DisplayName "TestDirectoryReaders" - …
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

As you can see in the output, the application assigned permissions are correctly returned.  The request for what permissions are required return the same ones that are granted.

Also one odd thing, why are the permissions doubled up?

Answer (score 0):

Woot!  Found the answer:

Also needs permission:
`RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory`

Hint to answer came from
[Insufficient privileges to create group with Assingable to Role True](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1028327/insufficient-privileges-to-create-group-with-assin)